# How to send info in URL?

Tags: django, django-forms, url-encoding

I am trying to create a product filter.
I am sending the user choice in URL 
if the user select size = L then using `request.GET`

I am receiving:
`{'size': ['L']}`

But I want to receive: `{'size':{'op':'in','attri':'L'}}`

Is this possible?
Please help

my models are

```
class ProductAttribute(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    op = models.CharField(max_length=20,default='in')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('slug', )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_formfield_name(self):
        return slugify('attribute-%s' % self.slug, allow_unicode=True)

    def has_values(self):
        return self.values.exists()


class AttributeChoiceValue(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(
        ProductAttribute, related_name='values', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('name', 'attribute')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    attributes = HStoreField(default={})



q2 = AttributeChoiceValue.objects.filter(attribute__name='size')
```

My size filter(filter.py) is:

```
size = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(queryset=q2.values_list('name', flat=True).distinct(),widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

I am currently using the following query to filter my database in views.py

```
result = Product.objects.all()

for key, value in request.GET:result = result.filter(**{'attributes__{}__in'.format(key): value})
```

I want to make it

```
a=request.GET
for key, value in a:
result = result.filter(**{'attributes__{}__{}'.format(key,a['op']): value})
```

so that if I even use Price range as filter my query filter accordingly will be

```
attributes__price__range
```

Comment: what is `'op':'in'` and where it comes from? can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

You can send info to your views via "path converters":
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#path-converters

Or using regular expressions:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#using-regular-expressions